# Passing arguments into subset function in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
         GRID_TYPE    GAME_ID GAME_EVENT_ID PLAYER_ID   PLAYER_NAME    TEAM_ID             TEAM_NAME PERIOD
1 Shot Chart Detail 0021500003             6    201939 Stephen Curry 1610612744 Golden State Warriors      1
2 Shot Chart Detail 0021500003             9    201939 Stephen Curry 1610612744 Golden State Warriors      1
3 Shot Chart Detail 0021500003            14    201939 Stephen Curry 1610612744 Golden State Warriors      1
4 Shot Chart Detail 0021500003            19    201939 Stephen Curry 1610612744 Golden State Warriors      1
5 Shot Chart Detail 0021500003            36    201939 Stephen Curry 1610612744 Golden State Warriors      1
6 Shot Chart Detail 0021500003            38    201939 Stephen Curry 1610612744 Golden State Warriors      1
7 Shot Chart Detail 0021500069             5    201939 Stephen Curry 1610612744 Golden State Warriors      1
8 Shot Chart Detail 0021500069           164    201939 Stephen Curry 1610612744 Golden State Warriors      2
9 Shot Chart Detail 0021500069           195    201939 Stephen Curry 1610612744 Golden State Warriors      2
```

I want to subset the data frame where `GAME_ID = "0021500003"`

So I have `gameID = "0021500003"`

and use `playerDF<- subset(stephShot, GAME_ID == gameID )`

but I get back an empty dataframe

When I use `playerDF<- subset(stephShot, GAME_ID =="0021500003" )` it works fine.

I tried searching google/SO and did not come across anything.

I would imagine its a simple fix but need a little help.

Comment: It works for me using your example.  Can you show a dput of the example dataset.

Comment: @akrun thanks for looking into my question. Yes, I was doing something wrong in my code. Is there a way to close out the question?

Comment: Deletion is always an option until someone upvotes an answer.